# Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="obj.two">Show Oops</button>

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="obj.edit">Edit Items</button>
```

whenever i click on show oops..In console the error is  Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Whereas my javascript code :

```
class User {

constructor()
    {
    this.name = "joker t-shirt";
    this.product = 200;
    this.Quantity = 4;
    this.total = this.product * this.Quantity;
    }


get two()  this is obj.two() ,but it spits out an error
   {    
   }
```

I am getting the error as object is not defined, kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

You must define `obj` as instance of `User()`:

```
var obj = new User();
```

```js
class User {

  constructor() {
    this.name = "joker t-shirt";
    this.product = 200;
    this.Quantity = 4;
    this.total = this.product * this.Quantity;
  }

  get two() { 
    console.log('Show oops button is Working...');
  }

  get edit() {
    console.log('Edit button is Working...');
  }

}

var obj = new User();
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="obj.two">Show Oops</button>

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="obj.edit">Edit Items</button>
```

Comment: Thank you much !! i was not known  either we can use as var or const for the new User(); for obj.

Comment: You are wellcome!